# Time Average of a function $f(\phi(t),t)$, $\phi(t)$ is only varying very slowly with time.

Tags: integration, derivatives, average, slowly-varying-functions

I am a bit stumped on a task. Namely I have the function:
\begin{align}
f(\phi(t),t) = \cos{(\omega (t-t_0))} \, \cos{\phi} + \cos^2{(\omega (t-t_0))}\,\sin{\phi}\,.
\end{align}
And my task is to calculate the time average. The only thing I know is that $\phi(t)$ is only varying very slowly with time. Personally, however, this means nothing to me. Maybe it's something I had 4 or 5 semesters ago, but it's not in my head anymore. I guess I just develop the function to $\phi$ using Taylor and then from the second order I can ignore the terms because $\frac{\text{d}^2\phi}{\text{d}t^2}$ is very small. But I am not sure. Can anyone here help me briefly?

Comment: For starters, you can try to reduce the function using the trig formulas for 2cosAcosB and cos^2A and then apply the avergaing linearly

Comment: That's clear, but I don't really see any advantage in that. As long as $\phi$ is unknown to me, this changes the complete curve and thus also the average. For example, if $\phi(t) = 0$ I would get the solution $\langle f \rangle = 0$, if $\phi(t) = \pi/2$ I would get the solution $\langle f \rangle = \frac{1}{2}$. If $\phi(t) = \omega(t-t_0)$, then I would get $\langle f \rangle = 1/2$. That's why I'm wondering how the information "$\phi(t)$ is only varying very slowly" can be used to calculate the time average.

Answer (score 0):

I have now gone the following way. But this is wrong, because the solution should be given at the end in quantities of $\phi(t)$.

---

Now, we assume that $\phi(t)$ is only varying very slowly with time. This means:
\begin{align*}
    \phi(t) &= \phi(t_0) + \dot{\phi}(t_0) (t-t_0) + \underbrace{\frac{\ddot{\phi}(t_0)}{2}}_{=\,\text{very small}} (t-t_0)^2 + \ldots \\
    &\approx \phi_0 + \omega_\phi (t-t_0)
\end{align*}
For the terms now applies:
\begin{align*}
    \langle\cos{\phi(t)}\,\cos{\left(\omega(t-t_0)\right)}\rangle &= \frac{1}{2}\left\langle\cos{\left[(\omega_\phi + \omega)t -\omega t_0 -\omega_\phi t_0 + \phi_0\right]}\right\rangle \\
    &\hspace{10pt} + \frac{1}{2}\left\langle\cos{\left[(\omega_\phi - \omega)t + \omega t_0 -\omega_\phi t_0 + \phi_0\right]}\right\rangle\\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0, & \omega_\phi \ne \omega \\ \cos{\left[\omega t_0 -\omega_\phi t_0 + \phi_0\right]}, & \omega_\phi = \omega \end{array}\right. \\
    \langle\cos^2{\left(\omega(t-t_0)\right)}\,\sin{\phi(t)}\rangle &= \frac{1}{4}\left\langle\sin{\left[(2\omega+\omega_\phi)t - 2\omega t_0 - \omega_\phi t_0 + \phi_0\right]}\right\rangle \\
    &\hspace{10pt} -\frac{1}{4} \left\langle\sin{\left[(2\omega-\omega_\phi)t -2\omega t_0 + \omega_\phi t_0 - \phi_0\right]}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle\sin\left[\phi(t)\right]\rangle \\
    &= \frac{1}{4}\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0, & \omega_\phi \ne \omega \\ \sin{\left[2\omega t_0 - \omega_\phi t_0 + \phi_0\right]}, & \omega_\phi = 2\omega \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
The final solution is now:
\begin{align*}
    \langle f(\phi(t),t) \rangle = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & \omega_\phi \ne \omega, \omega_\phi \ne 2\omega \\
    \frac{1}{2}\cos{\left[\omega t_0 -\omega_\phi t_0 + \phi_0\right]}, & \omega_\phi = \omega \\
    \frac{1}{4}\sin{\left[2\omega t_0 - \omega_\phi t_0 + \phi_0\right]}, & \omega_\phi = 2\omega \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}